# Why does selenium click only the first line of code and not the two others?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tested first if the first line of code to click the XPath which works but then when I add a second line of code to click By.name() it doesn't work, so I tried to change in XPath and then in CSS selectors but it only clicks the first one the (XPath code of line). I have tried but it doesn't seem to click the two other elements.
What I found out was that it only clicking what was on the first page, didn't really matter what was on the new page and I told to click on an element that I wanted to do. I'm using the `Selenium version 3.141.59`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ae65255\\Desktop\\java_gui\\chromedriver.exe");       
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/collections/new");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"product-loop\"]/div[@data-alpha='S-LINE JOGGER BLACK']")).click(); //only this one work 
    driver.findElement(By.name("button")).click(); //second click dosen't work?
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cart")).click(); //this dosen't work too?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some wait to let the page load before locating the element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("button")));
button.click();
```

The third locator `By.linkText("Cart")` didn't work because the button doesn't have `Cart` text, it's in the `data-text` and `value` attributes.

As a side note, you should use `By.partialLinkText()` when looking for partial text.